# Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::UsersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been developing API, but when I access the endpoint `Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::UsersController, expected /Users/toshikiinami/Desktop/billing/app/controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb to define it` comes out.

- I use rails 4.2.3

Any ideas to configure the subdomain endpoint properly?

`config/routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do    
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/'  do
    scope module: :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:index]
    end
  end
end
```

`controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb`

```
class UsersController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    render 'test' => 'json'
  end
end
```

`/etc/hosts`

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 api.localhost.local
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is as stated:

`controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb` defines `UsersController` class, not `Api::V1::UsersController`.

The solution looks as follows:

```
#controllers/api/v1/users_controller.rb
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ActionController::Base
      def index
        render json: { test: 'test' }, status: :ok
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! but I have following error now `Missing template api/v1/users/testaaa with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:`

Comment: @Toshi google it and you'll for sure be good ;) for now the issue you asked about is solved. If you won't be able to resolve it, ask a new question :)

Comment: @Toshi try `render json: { test: 'test' }, status: :ok` ;)

Comment: @Toshi did you see the edited answer? It should not now throw the error it did before

Comment: I looked up and installed 'responders' gem but it doesn't work...maybe another issue. Usually respond_to 'json' would be the defacto when developing api. `respond_to json` means 'returns json format' if anything else is specified right?

Comment: @Toshi `means 'returns json format' if anything else is specified right` yep :)

Comment: Thanks you so much, and I got it now :))